# subgroup structure of $S_4$

Tags: group-theory

In the list of Young subgroups of $S_4,$ we find $\langle(12)\rangle, \langle(13)\rangle, \langle(14)\rangle, \langle(23)\rangle, \langle(24)\rangle, \langle(34)\rangle,$ but we don't find  $\langle(12)(34)\rangle, \langle(13)(24)\rangle,\langle(14)(23)\rangle,$ while they are all isomorphic to $S_2.$ I'm confused.

Comment: What is a young subgroup?

Comment: @ChrisEagle: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Young_subgroup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Young subgroup is the direct product of the symmetric groups on the components of the partition. While all these groups are abstractly isomorphic to $S_2$, only the first batch you list is actually $S_2$ on a two-element subset of $\{1,2,3,4\}$, whereas e.g. in the first example of the second batch the group would also have to include $(12)$ and $(34)$ separately in order to be the Young subgroup for the partition $\{1,2,3,4\}=\{1,2\}\cup\{3,4\}$. You can't write down a partition such that $\langle(12)(34)\rangle$ contains all combinations of all permutations on all subsets forming the partition.